# tf.reduce_sum(lastconv,axis=2) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.greater(lastconv, 0), tf.float32), axis=2) used in place of Mean Pooling?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am working with eye trajectories data and convolution neural networks. 
I was asked to use `tf.reduce_max(lastconv, axis=2)` in place of MaxPooling layer and `tf.reduce_sum(lastconv,axis=2) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.greater(lastconv, 0), tf.float32), axis=2)` in place of MeanPooling layer.

I have following questions, for which I am not able to get clarity. It would be great it you can make me understand.

1. Is internal computation of reduce_max function and a conventional MaxPool layer same? The output of both is different in terms of dimensionality, why so? I don't quite understand why?
2. Why can’t we just use `tf.reduce_mean` function for MeanPooling, like how `tf.reduce_max` is used for MaxPooling?
3. `tf.reduce_sum(lastconv,axis=2) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.greater(lastconv, 0), tf.float32), axis=2)` How is this working as a MeanPool computational wise and how is it different `tf.reduce_mean` ?

I am sure you can tell that i don't quiet understand what `reduce_max/min/mean/sum` are doing to input tensors and what is the learning the model takes away from these functions?

About data: the shape of data is (24,4,15,2,87236), where 24 are subjects, 4 temperature variations and 15 trails, 2x87236 is continuous eye gaze (2 because of x-axis and y-axis). I am using LeaveOneOut CV where I train on 22 subjects and test and validate on 1 subject each.

After I create train, validation and test sets, the final input that goes in the model is (22,60[4x15],2,87236) , (1,60,2,87236) and (1,60,2,87236) respectively.

I hope I have provided enough information about the dilemma  I am in, for you to help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reduce_max takes the maximum over an entire dimension, so e.g. if dim=1, it would reduce

```
[[1,2,3],
 [2,1,3],
 [1,4,0]]
```

to

```
[3,3,4]
```

Max pooling on the other hand looks at the maximum in some shifting window, see e.g. https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Max-pooling_/_Pooling. The main difference here is the shape of the window. Where with reduce_max that window is a whole slice of the tensor, with max pooling it's some specified rectangle. This also results in different dimensions (to really understand this, you could look at what happens if you use keepdims=True in reduce_max).

Your replacement of the meanpooling layer seems to not take the arithmetic average, but instead divide by the number of positive elements (as opposed to the number of elements in general). That's probably why you can't use reduce_mean.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me quite some clarity.